# Flex - Panel doesnot resize after adjusting DividerBox

Tags: layout, apache-flex, panel

Hi have a folding panel as one of the components of the divider box. It can be expanded and collapsed, and the divider box adjust itself on expand/collapse.

But once i manually move/adjust the divider the divider box doesn't auto-adjust when i collapse the panel. Empty space id hence created. Any help appreciated

Comment: make sure all 'inner' boxes are set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use resizeToContent property of DivideBox
check the following code

```
<mx:HDividedBox width="500" height="200" resizeToContent="true"/>
```

resizeToContent property is used to adjust your container according to the child width, height
when you collaps the panel, according to the new height and width, a dividebox will adjust it self.

```
resizeToContent was set true. And it is working fine until I adjust the divider. Once it is adjusted, it wont get re-sized with the child size.
```

resizeToContent property will work when user not set width or height propery to container in above HDivdebox i set width and height propery thats why it doesn't work...
try following code...
 here in below code i use HDivideBox and TitleWindow as its child... TitleWindow has its own height and width and HDivideBox's resizeToContent property is set to true. when user click on close button it's width decrease and  HDivideBox is resize itself according to childrens total width

```
protected function t1_closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
    {
        t1.width = 50;  
    }

protected function t2_closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
    {
        t2.width = 50;
    }

<mx:HDividedBox  resizeToContent="true">
        <mx:TitleWindow id="t1" width="150" height="100" showCloseButton="true"  close="t1_closeHandler(event)"/>
        <mx:TitleWindow id="t2" width="150" height="100" showCloseButton="true" close="t2_closeHandler(event)"/>
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

Comment: resizeToContent was set true. And it is working fine until I adjust the divider. Once it is adjusted, it wont get re-sized with the child size.